# BadRequestError: projection and keys_only cannot both be set

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Hi i am getting error on this line. Its working in local.
I just deleted all the entities at appspot.

```
#query line
sent_list = db.GqlQuery("SELECT email FROM MailListNew WHERE active = True")
#error line
sent_count = sent_list.count()


projection and keys_only cannot both be set
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1511, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1505, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1253, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1077, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 547, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 545, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~merdiven-mailservice/1.361030076545076265/index.py", line 89, in post
    sent_count = sent_list.count()
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 2120, in count
    result = raw_query.Count(limit=limit, **kwargs)
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/datastore.py", line 1670, in Count
    batch = self.GetBatcher(config=config).next()
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_query.py", line 2671, in next
    return self.next_batch(self.AT_LEAST_ONE)
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_query.py", line 2708, in next_batch
    batch = self.__next_batch.get_result()
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 604, in get_result
    return self.__get_result_hook(self)
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_query.py", line 2450, in __query_result_hook
    self._batch_shared.conn.check_rpc_success(rpc)
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_rpc.py", line 1216, in check_rpc_success
    raise _ToDatastoreError(err)
BadRequestError: projection and keys_only cannot both be set
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the query to:

```
sent_list = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM MailListNew WHERE active = True")
```

or (better):

```
sent_list = db.GqlQuery("SELECT __key__ FROM MailListNew WHERE active = True")
```

Comment: I need to loop over each email so i tried first query and its working now thanks.